# Repast HPC Not Installing correctly on UBUNTU

Tags: repast-hpc

When installing the netcdf the following error occurs using the installation script.

```
configure: error: Can't find or link to the z library. Turn off netCDF-4 and      opendap with --disable-netcdf-4 --disable-dap, or see config.log for errors.
```

Any help massively appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? The installs script included as part of the manual install disables netCDF-4 with  --disable-netcdf-4, so that should be enough to make it work. Can you provide the relevant part of the config.log showing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `libhdf5-dev` is installed with `dpkg -L libhdf5-dev`. If it isn't try installing it with with `apt-get install libhdf5-dev` and running the netcdf installation again.